# Antlr rule for numbers and hex

Tags: antlr4

I'm writing a parser for libretro datfiles. It's my first antlr grammar and parser, so please forgive me for the lack of best practices.

But man, how cool antlr is, can't believe it was that simple to get me this far :)

```
game (
    name "10-Yard Fight (World, set 1)"
    year "1983"
    developer "Irem"
    rom ( name 10yard.zip size 62708 crc 8f401426 md5 040dc0827e184b8da9b91499f96c1fce sha1 8b15a2e54e9fdded3d61205bac6535ccc7b41271 )
)
```

And my grammar:

```
grammar Datafile;

game: GAME LP
        gameBody+
        RP;

gameBody: gameName
          | year
          | developer
          | rom+
          ;

rom: ROM LP
          size
        | crc
        | md5
        | serial
        | sha1
        RP;
size: SIZE NUMBER;
crc: CRC HEX;
md5: MD5 HEX;
sha1: SHA1 HEX;
serial: SERIAL STRING;

gameName: NAME STRING;
year: YEAR STRING;
developer: DEVELOPER STRING;

//keywords
GAME: 'game';
ROM: 'rom';
NAME: 'name';
YEAR: 'year';
DEVELOPER: 'developer';
SIZE: 'size';
CRC: 'crc';
MD5: 'md5';
SHA1: 'sha1';
SERIAL: 'serial';
LP: '(';
RP: ')';

STRING : '"' ( '\\"' | . )*? '"';
WS  :   [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;

NUMBER: DIGIT+ ([.,] DIGIT+)?;

HEX: [a-fA-F0-9]+;

fragment LETTER: [A-Za-z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
```

So I'm not being very strict on capturing things like year/developer via using a generic String rule, because sometimes dates are string in the dataset, I'll handle those on the parser logic.

But I bumped into a problem with the hex values. As they are not escaped as in certain languages via `0x` prefix. What's happening is that if I have a `crc 0001100` then the parser captures this as a `NUMBER` and not a `HEX`.

Is there a way out of this, or do I just map both `size` and `crc sha1 md5` as hex and deal with parsing logic on the parser?

Another issue I bumped was trying to figure out how to capture the filename (rom -> name), that could be any valid file name, and I'm not being able to write a rule that captures that.

Hope anyone could chime in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some special syntax for hex numbers, the Lexer will not be able to identify them as such.  You only know that something should be interpreted as a hex number by the context.  Parser rules gives you context.

So:

```
hexNumber: HEX | NUMBER;
crc: CRC hexNumber;
md5: MD5 hexNumber;
sha1: SHA1 hexNumber;
```

Now you’ll have a HexNumberContext in your parse tree and will know how to interpret it.

You could also just do:

```
crc: CRC ( HEX | NUMBER)
```

You can try both and look at the resulting parse tree and context classes to see which you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinkning that you could use LEXER modes to force the number to be parsed as a hex number.  I'm not too happy about Lexer modes as I'm still an ANTLR4 newbie, but I thought of something like this:

```
CRC : 'crc' ->pushMode(HexOnly);
MD5 : 'md5' ->pushMode(HexOnly);
SHA1: 'sha1' ->pushMode(HexOnly); 
...
mode HexOnly;
HEX1: [a-fA-F0-9]+ ->popMode;
... any other HexOnly mode thing
```

In the exampe I used HEX1 as I find when I have modes invarably I have a token type that is also used elsewhere, and as I'm still learning to think "ANTLR4" I will hack my way to a solution until I learn an elegant solution.

I find Lexer modes are sort of non-elegant so far.
Cool but come with baggage.